# Want to execute multiple TestNG test from a class for every row of data in my .CSV file

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am trying to run multiple test(@Test) from a class for each row of test data in my csv file. i am using testNG facory and dataprovider. For example lets say i have test1, test2, and Test3 test methods in my class and 3 set(row) of test data in my CSV file. now when i run it, run secquence follows like this:
    test1
    test1
    test1
    test2
    test2
    test2
    test3
    test3
    test3

but this is what i am looking for, i want my test to run in following sequence:
    test1
    test2
    test3
    test1
    test2
    test3
    test1
    test2
    test3

**below is my sample code(Replace my csv data with test data int he data provider it self)**

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestWithDataProviderAndFactory {
     private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
        public TestWithDataProviderAndFactory(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        @DataProvider(name = "dp")
        public static Object[][] getData() {
            return new Object[][]{
                    {"Rajeev", "Kumar"},
                    {"Sanjeev", "Kumar"},
                    {"Jony", "Dip"}
            };
        }

        @Test
        public void test1() {
            System.out.println("This is test 1");
            System.out.println("First Name: "+ firstName);
        }

        @Test
        public void test2() {
            System.out.println("This is test 2");
            System.out.println("Last Name: "+ lastName);
        }
}
```

**output:(this is what i am getting)**

```
This is test 1
First Name: Rajeev
This is test 1
First Name: Jony
This is test 1
First Name: Sanjeev
This is test 2
Last Name: Kumar
This is test 2
Last Name: Dip
This is test 2
Last Name: Kumar
```

**But, i want to execute the test like below:**

```
This is test 1
First Name: Rajeev
This is test 2
Last Name: Kumar
This is test 1
First Name: Sanjeev
This is test 2
Last Name: Kumar
This is test 1
First Name: Jony
This is test 2
Last Name: Dip
```

Thanks in Advance for help!!

Comment: Use group-by-instances="true" on the suite or test tag in testng.xml....  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations

Comment: thanks @Grasshopper - group-by-instances="true" worked for me.

Comment: @Grasshopper - Perhaps you could add that as an answer so that it can be accepted and the question closed ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Took ur suggestion and added as answer. Thx

Comment: @Sandip Can you please go ahead and accept the answer from `@Grasshopper` since his suggestion help you get your problem resolved ?

Comment: @ Krishnan Mahadevan - Done thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group-by-instances="true"` on the suite or test tag in testng.xml. Refer to this link for more details in the [official documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations).